# Check for number of rows on LEFT JOINED query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to check if each joined part of query returned some results or not.

```
first table result set LEFT JOIN second table result set LEFT JOIN third table result set.
```

I was thinking of checking the first column of every set - empty or not, but not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the existence of a field you were matching on for each of your left joins.  The field would be NULL if there is no match.

Example

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN `second table`.joinfield IS NULL THEN 'No Match' ELSE 'Match' END as is_match
```

etc.